# Why does absolute path depend on where we call the script?

Tags: ruby, path

I have the following structure in my computer:

```
.
├── README.md
├── Rakefile
├── lib
│   ├── box_office.rb
│   └── movies.csv
└── spec
    └── box_office_spec.rb
```

When I run `box.office.rb`, I want to load the `movies.csv` file. If I hard-code the path, it works:

```
current_directory = Dir.pwd
file_path = "#{current_directory}/lib/movies.csv"
puts file_path
```

How can I do this without hard-coding the path (this `lib/` directory)? I need the current directory of the file, where I do ruby: `XXXX.rb`.

I've tried:

```
current_directory = File.expand_path(File.dirname(__dir__))
puts current_directory

current_directory = Dir.pwd

path = Pathname.new(__FILE__)
p path.realpath
```

Comment: `__dir__` does not depend on where you call the script. What's wrong with that solution?

Comment: what are you trying to do with `.csv` files in this project? But you should be able to use relative path as @TomLord has suggested.

Comment: yeah it works. File.dirname(__dir__) works, not with the expand_path